# how to Remove payment method, shipping information and shipping method

Tags: magento-1.9, products-management

I want remove Shipping Information, Shipping method, and Payment method for now i don't need to add all of this, i only want customer can view product detail and go for checkout.

i tried to remove it at time of checkout it giving me error message that process can not go further for checkout.

Answer (score 1):

Please use **virtual** product type. It removes everything about the shipping.

For the payment enable single option **Money Order**

Answer (score 1):

Amasty give a good idea.But if you want checkout all type of Product using checkout

Then follow below steps:

**step1:** `make shipping same as billing address`.

**Step2:**`On Billing save action programmatically set free shipping as shipping method`.

may like:

add below code which set shipping method on checkout after `$this->getOnepage()->saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId);`

```
$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod);
 $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
```

**Step3:** `Also on billing save action programmatically  save Zero Subtotal payment as  payment or any available payment gateway`. exmaple:

```
$quote=$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()
        $paymentData = $this->_preparePaymentData($paymentData);
        if ($quote->isVirtual()) {
            $quote->getBillingAddress()->setPaymentMethod('free');
        } else {
            // check if shipping address is set
            if (is_null($quote->getShippingAddress()->getId())) {
               // error
            }
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setPaymentMethod(
                isset($paymentData['method']) ? $paymentData['method'] : null
            );
        }

        if (!$quote->isVirtual() && $quote->getShippingAddress()) {
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        }

        $total = $quote->getBaseSubtotal();
        try {
            $payment = $quote->getPayment();
            $payment->importData(array('method' => 'free'));
            $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)
                ->collectTotals()
                ->save();
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {

        }
```

**Step4:** `Goto review step using json return like`:

```
try {

            // get section and redirect data
            $redirectUrl = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getPayment()->getCheckoutRedirectUrl();
            if (empty($result['error']) && !$redirectUrl) {
                $this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_review');
                $result['goto_section'] = 'review';
                $result['update_section'] = array(
                    'name' => 'review',
                    'html' => $this->_getReviewHtml()
                );
            }
            if ($redirectUrl) {
                $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
            }
        } catch (Mage_Payment_Exception $e) {
            if ($e->getFields()) {
                $result['fields'] = $e->getFields();
            }
            $result['error'] = $e->getMessage();
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $result['error'] = $e->getMessage();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            $result['error'] = $this->__('Unable to set Payment Method.');
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result))
```